# Is this jquery refresh script safe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I use this script to update a `div`, gathering new information constantly. It works well in every browser, except in Google Chrome where it hangs after a while and the browser turns blue and a small sad graphic tells me there's something wrong. The rest of the browser stays intact, it's only the affected tab so it has to do something with this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("SANAjax();", 500); 
    $(function(){
        SANAjax = function(){
            $("#target").load("page.php");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Is it not safe to refresh a `div` that many times? Will it overload or what not?

Comment: 1) Why are you declaring your SANAjax function insider of an anonymous function inside a jQuery call? 2) Updating every 500ms seems a little much, why not up that to 1+ seconds?

Comment: 1) How would you do it? 2) What is the difference, is it harmful in some way to refresh so much?

Comment: Look at 321X's answer.  Just like that.  As for the refresh... it isn't really harmful, but if you have 1000 people on that page at .5 secs per call... that is potentially 2000 pages requests per second.

Comment: @Paparappa For a few visitors on your website 500 milliseconds is not a problem. Where there is a pike and there are (lets say) 50 visitors online at your site, does this require 100 connections PER second!

Comment: Okey well i have alot of visitiors at my site. I havent used this script on the real site but it can have around 100-1000 members online all the time, of course not everyone is using this page at the same time. But the risk is out there, if i set it to refresh every 2 seconds, would that spare me risks or should i look for another solution?

Comment: @Paparappa It sure reduces the risk! You can calculate what the timeout can be, if you know how many connections per second you webserver can handle. If you have a dedicated webserver you can probably handle more than when you have a virtual (/shared) webserver. HINT: Ask your hosting provider! At least use my code snippet. You will save a lot of 'unneeded connections' already!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it a bit different than that.

**Untested:**

```
$(function(){
    SANAjax();
});

function SANAjax(){
    $('#target').load('page.php', function(){
        setTimeout(SANAjax, 500);
    });
}
```

This makes sure a new request is being made after the current one is finished.
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: +1 Words out of my mouth, with polish! I'd just like to note that this method means AJAX requests won't pile up if each one takes longer than (in this case) 500ms; the next one is only called after the previous is complete.

Comment: 1) Why would you do different? 2) As most untested code it doesent work :P

Comment: Let's say that your webserver is pretty busy and 1 request takes up to 500 milliseconds. What do you think is going to happen? I predict a soon to follow connection not available situation.

Comment: Code is fixed. I was missing a character. setTimout instead of setTimeout!

Comment: It works great, i will think a bit more if im getting this code published to my site since its obvoiusly a big risk if i have many visitors.

Comment: May I ask if you know how established chat software does this. They must somehow refresh often since they even tell you when someones typing and so on. Is there a way for the script to tell if thers been a change and then update? Maybe this is a stupid question.

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. Check this link for information about the Push technology: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology#HTTP_server_push. This might give you some ideas. The easiest thing is just wait for every one is using a HTML5 compatible browser ;-)

Comment: Hi, You might check this page: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/ It might help you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The simple way

```
$(function(){
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#target').load('page.php');
        }, 500)
});
```